# How to Change Form Field Width in Sharepoint?

Tags: javascript, css, forms, list, sharepoint

I am new to coding and really new to javascript and have been left with the task of trying to maintain a SharePoint form that was created by someone else. I am not too familiar with SharePoint Designer or Javascript. 
All I need to do is change the width of a form field in a SharePoint List. Here is the code I tried to come up with...pretty sure it's not even close.

```
$('select[id^="Metric_x0020_Name"')("<style>=width: 602px;");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery

```
$('#Metric_x0020_Name').css('width', '602px');
```

Maybe try using CSS to adjust the styling? It would look like this

```
#Metric_x0020_Name{
  width: 602px;
}
```

Put this after the SharePoint specific styling. You may need to increase the specificity of the CSS if this isn't overwriting what currently exists. In Google Chrome you can check to see what styling is used by right clicking the element and then inspect.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried both suggestions and still can't get it to overwrite. I checked the styling in Chrome and got this `<select id="Metric_x0020_Name_e2f3e5ef-aaff-4852-b4f3-aedd23678d53_$LookupField" title="Metric Name"><option selected="selected" value="0">(None)</option><option value="403">`

Comment: Using CSS instead of JavaScript/jQuery like @Chad suggests is probably the best approach. [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Simple_selectors) let you target almost any HTML element. To grab the `select` element in your example HTML, instead of its ID you could get it by its `title` attribute: `[title="Metric Name"]{width:602px;}` (Grabbing elements by partial attribute values is supported on fewer browsers, less efficient, and more likely to give you unexpected results than grabbing elements by their complete attribute values.)

Comment: Great! Thanks so much for your help! I finally got it to work.